# printing elements of a list

Tags: python, list

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Printing elements out of list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2501675/printing-elements-out-of-list)

i have a lists that have N items, eg `[item1,item2, item3, value ]` then i would like to print

```
print' %s.%s.%s = %s' % (item1,item2, item3, value)
```

My problem is 'N' variable, and for any cases of 'N', i  would like to print

```
print' %s.%s.%s....%s (N times) = %s' % (item1,item2,item3,... , itemN, value)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`str.join()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.join).

```
print '.'.join(str(x) for x in L[:-1]) + ' = %s' % L[-1]
```